# io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni multi threading doesn't work (Quarkus)

Tags: java, multithreading, quarkus, mutiny

I try to perform 2 different operations with different threads each.Here is my code :

```
 Uni.combine().all()
            .unis(getItem(), getItemDetails())
            .asTuple().subscribe().with(tuple -> {
                context.setItem(tuple.getItem1());
                context.setItemDetails(tuple.getItem2());
            });
```

Methods :

```
public Uni<ItemResponse> callGetItem(){
    Supplier<ItemResponse> supplier = () -> itemService.getItem("item_id_1");
    return Uni.createFrom().item(supplier);
}

public Uni<ItemDetailsResponse> callGetItemDetail(){
        Supplier<ItemDetailsResponse> supplier = () -> itemService.getItemDetail("dummy_item_id");
        return Uni.createFrom().item(supplier) ;
    }
```

But when i run the code both **callGetItem()** and **callGetItemDetail()** methods works in the same thread (executor-thread-0).

Where am i doing wrong?

Edit:

When i give an executor service  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2) for my Unis,
They still work in single thread. I mofified callGetItem() and callGetItemDetail() as :

```
 public Uni<ItemResponse> callGetItem(){
    Supplier<ItemResponse> supplier = () -> itemService.getItem("item_id_1");
    return Uni.createFrom().item(supplier).emitOn(executor);
}

public Uni<ItemDetailsResponse> callGetItemDetail(){
        Supplier<ItemDetailsResponse> supplier = () -> itemService.getItemDetail("dummy_item_id");
        return Uni.createFrom().item(supplier).emitOn(executor) ;
    }
```

executor is :

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

but they still works in same thread. Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: The method themselves yeah, but what about the actual supplier? Try to access the thread(s) that effectively run `itemService.getItem("item_id_1")` and `itemService.getItemDetail("dummy_item_id")`.

Comment: @sp00m yes. Also itemService.getItem("item_id_1") and itemService.getItemDetail("dummy_item_id") methods run in the same thread too. They work sequentially

Comment: Your code, or at least the portion you show here, doesn't really define on which threads should subscription/emission happen. Therefore, they all happen on the original thread. See e.g. https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/emission-threads for more info.

Comment: @Ladicek I edited the question. Can you take a look please?

Comment: I guess that would be expected -- I should have probably pointed you to https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/emit-subscription instead. If I understand your question correctly, you want `runSubscriptionOn`, not `emitOn`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are composing different `Uni`s using `Uni.combine().all().unis().asTuple()`, the combined `Uni` will emit its result (combination) after the last element has emitted its item.

The last (upstream) `Uni` will have its item emitted (as is the case for other `Uni`s as well) on whatever `Thread` that you have declaratively set it to emit on. Hence the combination `Uni` will follow execution on the same calling `Thread`.

As a result, if you are accessing the combined group values, you will be accessing these on the same execution carrier `Thread`.